# These are two similar problems on estimating error; Why does one involve taking a linear approximation, and not the other?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

I'm having a hard time understanding where to apply linear approximation. These two problems seem very similar to me, except one does not use linear approximation:

---

Problem 1: Suppose that you measure the velocity of an object by measuring that it takes $t$ second to travel $x$ meters. The measurement error is $Δx$ meters in distance, and the error in time is $Δt$ seconds. What is the absolute value of the error in the linear approximation for the velocity?

$$v + Δv = \frac{x + Δx}{t + Δt}$$
$$v + Δv = (x+Δx)\cdot(t+Δt)^{-1}$$
$$v + Δv = (x+Δx) \frac {1}{t} (1+\frac{Δt}{t})^{-1}$$

Taking the linear approximation of the right-hand term:

$$v + Δv \approx (x+Δx) \frac {1}{t} (1-\frac{Δt}{t})$$

Then multiplying out:

$$v + Δv ≈ \frac{x}{t} + \frac{Δx}{t} − \frac{x \cdot Δt}{t^{2}} - \frac{Δx \cdot Δt}{t^2}$$

Dropping the last term due to being quadratic:

$$v + Δv ≈ \frac{x}{t} + \frac{Δx}{t} − \frac{x \cdot Δt}{t^{2}}$$

Since $v = \frac{x}{t}$ it can be subtracted from both sides, $$Δv \approx \frac{Δx}{t} − \frac{x \cdot Δt}{t^{2}}$$

---

Problem 2: Suppose you measure the velocity of a mosquito to be  $v$  m/s with an error of  $Δv$  m/s. We approximate the mosquito to weigh approximately equal to a grain of rice, which is on the order of magnitude of  $m$  kg. What is the error in the kinetic energy? Assume there is no rotational velocity.

$$K = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

$$K + ΔK = \frac{1}{2}m(v + Δv)^2$$

$$K + ΔK = \frac{1}{2}m(v^2 + 2vΔv + Δv^2)$$

Dropped the last term due to being quadratic:

$$K + ΔK \approx \frac{1}{2}m(v^2 + 2vΔv)$$

Multiplied out:

$$K + ΔK \approx \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + mvΔv$$

Since $K = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$, subtracted from both sides:

$$ΔK \approx mvΔv$$

---

Why does the first problem take a linear approximation to help solve for error, but the second doesn't? Is there something I'm missing about what makes a variable special?

Comment: The first is using a linear approximation to convert errors in $x$ and $t$ given in the problem statement into an error in $v$. The second problem gives an error in $v$ at the outset, so there is no need to make this conversion from errors in $x$ and $t$ first. The calculation of $\Delta K$ is still a linear approximation in $\Delta v$ (thus "dropped the last term due to being quadratic"). They just didn't bother to explicitly label it as such for you.